# Correlating two GROUP BY queries to get two distinct counts

Tags: mysql

I have a `Kill` table:

```
PlayerID
VictimID
WipeID
```

Where the `PlayerID` is the "Killer"

This gets me the Players in order of Most Killed along with their count of kills

```
SELECT PlayerID,COUNT(*) AS count FROM `Kill` WHERE WipeID = ? GROUP BY PlayerID ORDER BY count DESC
```

And this gets me the Players in order of the Most Unique Kills along with their count of unique kills

```
SELECT VictimID,COUNT(*) AS count FROM `Kill` WHERE PlayerID = ? AND WipeID = ? GROUP BY VictimID
```

I need to correlate the two in order to produce a leaderboard based on unique kills, but to also include the count of non-unique kills.

Any help appreciated!

> Needless to say this is for a game and I'm not actually a psychopath <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want Count(DISTINCT PlayerID) and Count(DISTINCT VictimID) I think.